# How to configure multiple Spring beans and choose which one to use? Is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am currently writing a TDEE calculator which "Total Daily Energy Expenditure". In other words, an approximate amount of calories you burn a day.

There are three different formulas. I want to give the end-user a choice of which formula they want to chose to calculate.

Right now I'm following [Spring Structure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

As I was creating my packages and their respective classes, I realized that the service class was going to have the same method `getTdee()` but just different implentations. Preferably, I would like to use an interface with three different implementations but I know you can't Autowire multiple beans. Is there some kind of solution to this or am I doomed to repeat myself with three packages each containing a controller, service, request payload?

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tdee")
public class Tdee{
    private TdeeService tdeeService

    @Inject
    public Tdee(TdeeService tdeeService){
        this.tdeeService = tdeeService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public getTdee(){
        return tdeeService.getTdee();
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Named
public class TdeeService{
   public int getTdee(){
       //logic here
   }
}
```

Preferably I would like to switch TdeeService to an interface and implement all three formulas as such:

```
@Named
KatchTdeeServiceImpl implements TdeeService{

    @Override
    public int getTdee(){
        //logic here
    }
}

@Named
HarrisTdeeServiceImpl implements TdeeService{

    @Override
    public int getTdee(){
        //logic here
    }
}


@Named
MiffinTdeeServiceImpl implements TdeeService{

    @Override
    public int getTdee(){
        //logic here
    }
}
```

To sum up my problem:

Ideally I would like to create one package with one service interface, three service implementations, a controller, and one payload class instead of three packages each with a controller, service, and a payload. Thank you!

Comment: I'd use a distinct `TDEECalculator` implementation for each formula and have a singleton service evaluate which implementation to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would determine which implementations to use based on some parameters passed by the user ?

Actually if you have multiple beans that implement the same interface , you can also inject them .One of the way is to use `@Qualifier` to specify which bean you want to inject (by bean name) :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tdee")
public class Tdee{

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("katchTdeeServiceImpl")
    private TdeeService katchTdeeServce;

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("harrisTdeeServiceImpl")
    private TdeeService harrisTdeeService;


    @PostMapping
    public getTdee(FooRequest request){

        if(request.isKatch()){
            katchTdeeServce.getTdee();
        }else if(requst.isHarris()){
            harrisTdeeService.getTdee();
        }

    }
}
```

Notes :

- You have to use `@Autowired` to inject . `@Inject` seems does not work
  with `@Qualifier`
- `@Qualifier` is the one from the spring package but not from `javax.inject`
- The default bean name is the lower camelCase of the class name . You can use `@Named("foo")` to define other name.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what has been said by using `@Qualifier` to uniquely identify the correct implementation, you can also autowire a list of beans, for example:

```
@Autowired
private List<TdeeService> tdeeServices;
```

This allows you to provide a more dynamic approach. For example, let's say you expand your `TdeeService` interface using the following method:

```
boolean isSupported(String calculationType);
```

You could implement it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean isSupported(String calculationType) {
    return "Harris".equals(calculationType);
}
```

Finally, I assume you'll have a `@RequestParam` somewhere that identifies which type of calculation you want to use. If that's the case, you could loop over `tdeeServices`, call the `isSupported()` method to find the right implementation, and use that to actually do the calculation.

For example:

```
@GetMapping
public int getTdee(@RequestParam String calculationType) {
    return tdeeServices
        .stream()
        // Filter out the TdeeService that are not supported
        .filter(service -> service.isSupported(calculationType))
        // Obtain the amount of calories
        .map(TdeeService::getTdee)
        // Get any of the results
        // Ideally, you'll only have one implementation that returns true for a specific calculationType
        // If multiple implementation returned 'true', any will be picked
        .findAny()
        // If the calculationType is not supported, an exception will be thrown
        .orElseThrow(UnsupportedCalculationTypeException::new);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wasn't planning on using query parameters. I was going to POST that information to the service.

Comment: @juice No problem, regardless of how you send the calculation type, the implementation would be very similar. The only difference would be how you obtain `calculationType` and pass it to the `filter(..)` statement.